# OAuth 2.0 - role of the resource server, authorization server and the resource owner

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am learning Oauth2.0 framework, and I am confused with the different roles of servers here. I need an application example to better understand this.

In the screenshot below taken from https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2 , can someone give me a real life example of a case , with role playing of these  different roles?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Ping Identity.
But I'm not trying to sell you anything! Just providing some helpful material.

I wrote a blog and created a youtube video to help out with this very thing! I think the maps above aren't the most helpful, so I've used some creative analogies to help walk you through the OAuth 2.0 framework.
https://developer.pingidentity.com/en/blog/posts/2019/oauth-flow-visualization.html

https://youtu.be/-3nwwH9PgHA